# Working of trashcan utility in tru64 Unix server.. or any other utility?

Tags: unix, data-recovery, tru64

I used this mktrashcan command  `mktrashcan deleteMe1 trashcan/`

And then i Deleted all the contents inside deleteMe1 directory`(rm -rf*)`.. But then what happend is only the two text files which are inside the deleteMe1(deleteMe2.txt, deleteMe3.txt) directory were moved into the trashcan folder.. Rest of the directories and files inside the directories were not foundd!!

Isn't there any other way, so that whatever is deleted, moves exactly the same way to the trashcan directory??? Or is there **Any Other Utility** that can perform the same task but in advance way..

```
mkdir deleteMe1
mkdir deleteMe1/deleteMe2
mkdir deleteMe1/deleteMe3

touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe2/deleteMe4.txt
touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe2/deleteMe5.txt
touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe3/deleteMe6.txt
touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe3/deleteMe7.txt
touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe2.txt
touch ./deleteMe1/deleteMe3.txt
```

Thankss..